# Error while calling functions within a function (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm getting errors saying that there is a syntax error for the "makeShortest" function that I defined.

- What is the problem here?
- Are there any other issues that might make this function not work at runtime?

```
def solution(A):
    idxDict = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        idxDict[A[i]].append(i)

    ans = -1
    A.sort()
    if len(A) <= 1:
        return ans

    hasAdj = 0
    for i in range(len(A) - 1):
        if A[i] != A[i + 1]:
            hasAdj += 1
            if hasAdj == 1:
                ans = makeShortest(idxDict[A[i]], idxDict[A[i + 1]])
            else:
                ans = min(ans, makeShortest(idxDict[A[i]], idxDict[A[i + 1]]))
    
    return ans

def makeShortest (list1, list2):
    ans = abs(list1[0] - list2[0])
    for k in range(len(list1)):
        for l in range(len(list2)):
            ans = min(ans, abs(list1[k] - list2[l])
    return ans
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're receiving?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.
The error is on ```def makeShortest (list1, list2) ```
with "pylint(syntax-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is ans2 in this line the error?

`ans = min(ans2, abs(list1[k] - idxDict[list2[l]))`

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. The error is on ```def makeShortest (list1, list2)```  with "invalid syntax(<unknown>, line 28) pylint(syntax-error) [28,34] " and line 28 is ```def makeShortest (list1, list2)```

Comment: I found another error in the same line: `ans = min(ans2, abs(list1[k] - idxDict[list2[l]))` The `idxDict` is missing a closing `]` so it should be `ans = min(ans2, abs(list1[k] - idxDict[list2[l]]))`

Comment: So I fixed my code for makeShortest() like how I did on the above question, but now I got error on the return statement of makeShortest with message "invalid syntax(<unknown>, line 33) pylint(syntax-error) [33, 6]

Comment: On the line 32 the code is missing a closing parenthesis `ans = min(ans, abs(list1[k] - list2[l])` It should be `ans = min(ans, abs(list1[k] - list2[l]))`